# $ in R... What is the equivalent in Python?

Tags: r, python-3.x

is there a way to refer to a specific column relative to a specific data frame in python like there is in R (data.frame$data)?

Comment: You can use `.`  `dataframe.data` to access the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually with `[]` => `data.frame["data"]`

Or for object like with `.` => `data.frame.data`

Answer (score 0):

You can generally use pandas to mimic R. You can use [] as below.

my_column = df['columnName']